# Show Jones polynomial is unique

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am trying to show that if we define a new invariant of knots $W(L)$ which follows the same rules as the Jones polynomial $V(L)$, so that it has value 1 on the unknot and satisfies the Skein relation $$t^{-1}W(L_+) - tW(L_-) + (t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})W(L_0)=0$$ then we must have $W(L)= V(L)$.

I know some things which I think may come in handy; 
if we set $t=1$ in the Skein relation, we get $W(L_+)=W(L_-)$. We can change any link diagram to a diagram of trivial links by changing crossings from over to under and vice versa. And the Jones polynomial of a union of $k$ trivial links is 
$(t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})^{k-1}$. I feel I should be able to put these together to get the result, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Use the skein relations and the Reidemeister moves to reduce the computation to  that of the unknot.

Comment: @anomaly how would I begin to do this?

Comment: Exactly like that. Applying the skein relation to a given knot gives an expression for $V(L)$ in terms of a knot with one fewer crossing and one in which the crossing is reversed; the Reidemeister moves simply the latter.

Comment: @user848484 What is your version of the Jones polynomial? The Kauffman bracket with writhe normalization?  I might try to denormalize $W$ (so that it depends on writhe in exactly the same way as the Kauffman bracket) and then show that, given a $W$ that satisfies this skein relation (if one existed) the denormalized version calculates the Kauffman bracket.  The converse is that you can show the Jones polynomial satisfies this skein relation. (Chapter 3 of Lickorish's book shows at least the converse.)

Comment: @KyleMiller I know of the Kauffman bracket definition of the Jones polynomial, but I hadn't thought of using it for this question, I've been trying to do so just from the rules given for the Jones poly and this new invariant. Is this possible?

Comment: @user848484 That depends on what the rules given to you for the Jones polynomial are (hence my question about what your definition for the Jones polynomial is).  Another option is that one can prove that there is a unique polynomial that satisfies this skein relation, but you would still need to show that the Jones polynomial satisfies the relation, too.  (Chapter 15 of Lickorish's book has how this works for the HOMFLY polynomial, a generalization of the Jones polynomial.  More context is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826407/jones-polynomial-invariance)